# Prevent IO.GetDirectories() from following symlinks

Tags: .net, linux, mono, io, symlink

While porting a .net application to Linux, using mono, I noticed that its implementation of `IO.GetDirectories` follows symlinks on Linux (the problem became obvious when my program reached `/home/clement/svn/obrowser/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib/tutorial/distrib`).

I couldn't find any documentation about this behaviour on mono's website, nor anywhere except for a tiny forum post.

Do you know a workaround to prevent `IO.GetDirectories` from following symlinks?

Comment: You have a symlink that points to a parent directory?

Comment: @Andrew: I don't, but my tests do include corner cases, and I can't afford an infinite loop of that kind :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [File.GetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx), the symlink will have the ReparsePoint attribute, I tested this with windows symlinks, and on ubuntu 10.10.

This wouldn't stop GetDirectories from recursively enumerating though, you would have to do your own recursion.

If you don't need cross platform support you might want to look at [Mono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T:Mono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo/*).

Comment: +1, thanks! For the reference, my research seems to indicate UnixDirectoryInfo always has `IsSymLink` set to false; the namespace to use seems to be Mono.Unix.UnixSymbolicLinkInfo.

Comment: See http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2005-October/thread.html#15136 for details on my previous comment, btw.

Comment: Tested this more comprehensively, and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a reference to **Mono.Posix** to your project, then the following code will test if a path points to a symbolic link:

```
Mono.Unix.UnixSymbolicLinkInfo i = new Mono.Unix.UnixSymbolicLinkInfo( path );
if( i.IsSymbolicLink ) ...
```

you can also test for other file types (like **Fifo**, **Socket**, **BlockDevice**, etc.) using

```
switch( i.FileType )
```